# boost::locale::boundary::segment_index throws bad_cast

Tags: c++, exception, boost, locale

I am trying to execute the code below. It is a code sample from boost documentation that perfoms word extraction from a text. Unfortunately it crashes with a bad_cast thrown.

```
using namespace boost::locale::boundary;
boost::locale::generator gen;
std::string text = "To be or not to be, that is the question.";
ssegment_index map(word, text.begin(), text.end(), gen("en_US.UTF-8"));
for (ssegment_index::iterator it = map.begin(), e = map.end(); it != e; ++it)
    std::cout << "\"" << *it << "\", ";
std::cout << std::endl;
```

The exception is thrown when trying to construct segment_index, I do not understand why.

Here is the call stack:

```
KernelBase.dll!00007ffc391ca839()   Unknown
vcruntime140d.dll!00007ffc13dfb230()    Unknown
Test.exe!std::_Throw_bad_cast() Line 66 C++
Test.exe!std::use_facet<boost::locale::boundary::boundary_indexing<char>>(const std::locale & _Loc) Line 439    C++
Test.exe!boost::locale::boundary::details::mapping_traits<std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>>,std::random_access_iterator_tag>::map(boost::locale::boundary::boundary_type t, std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>> b, std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>> e, const std::locale & l) Line 98  C++
Test.exe!boost::locale::boundary::details::mapping<std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>>>::mapping<std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>>>(boost::locale::boundary::boundary_type type, std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>> begin, std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>> end, const std::locale & loc) Line 127    C++
Test.exe!boost::locale::boundary::segment_index<std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>>>::segment_index<std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>>>(boost::locale::boundary::boundary_type type, std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>> begin, std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>> end, const std::locale & loc) Line 630 C++
Test.exe!main() Line 12 C++
```

I am using Visual Studio 2019 with boost 1.73 installed using vcpkg (vcpkg.exe install  boost-locale[icu]:x64-windows).

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Usually means a locale (facet) was not imbued or not defined for the (character type)